# How do I reset to servo position everytime I excecute a particular sequence

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, servo, robotics

I'm trying to make a prosthetic hand that can play rock, paper, scissors with a human. It is based on the premise that you push a button and it randomly selects a move to play. After each move, I'd like for it to return to a normal state after a few seconds delay, the human can then decide whom is victorious.

Code I have so far. It doesn't even stop after the degrees I've set, it just keeps turning. I have a cardboard prototype and it has come close to breaking because the servos just keep turning.

```
#include <Servo.h> //servo library

//Define servos
Servo servo1;
Servo servo2;
Servo servo3;
Servo servo4;

int pos = 0;

void setup()
//define servo signal inputs [digital PWM 2, 3, 4, 5]
{
  servo1.attach(2);
  servo2.attach(3);
  servo3.attach(4);
  servo4.attach(5);

}

void loop()
{
  void rEADY();
  //void rock();
  //void scissors();
  //void paper();
}

void rEADY()
{
  servo1.write(20);
  servo2.write(20);
  servo3.write(20);
  servo4.write(20);
  servo1.write(0);
  servo2.write(0);
  servo3.write(0);
  servo4.write(0);

}

void rock()
{
  servo1.write(180);
  servo2.write(180);
  servo3.write(180);
  servo4.write(180);
  servo1.write(0);
  servo2.write(0);
  servo3.write(0);
  servo4.write(0);
}

void scissors()
{
  servo1.write(180);
  servo2.write(180);
  servo3.write(0);
  servo4.write(0);
  servo1.write(0);
  servo2.write(0);
  servo3.write(0);
  servo4.write(0);
}

void paper()
{
  servo1.write(0);
  servo2.write(0);
  servo3.write(0);
  servo4.write(0);
  servo1.write(20);
  servo2.write(20);
  servo3.write(20);
  servo4.write(20);

}
```

Comment: do you realize that loop() repeats several thousand times every second? .... think about what your code is doing each iteration of loop()

Comment: @jsotola Thanks for replying :) I was working on it today and I did realise that I shouldn’t loop it. But i’m still a bit stuck on how to execute one off moves. Not sure if I’m looking at it the right way.

Comment: looping is ok ... look for `blinkWithoutDelay` sketch in the examples in the arduino IDE ... you can run a subroutine in the loop() block only once quite easily ... in setup(), set a flag ... in loop(), if flag is set, then run code and clear flag ... that's it ... the program will continue looping, but it will run the code only the first time through, because the second time through, the flag is no longer set .... you can easily add code that sets the flag every 10 seconds ... that will make the flag set at the begining of loop() again for a single repeat of the code once every 10 seconds